# Orientation of circles in $\Bbb C_\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Gamma$ be arbitrary and suppose $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \Gamma$, then for any mobius transformation $S$ we have,

$\{z:Im(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)\gt 0 \}$...........$(a)$

= $\{z:Im(Sz,Sz_1,Sz_2,Sz_3)\gt 0 \}$....$(b)$

=$S^{-1}\{z:Im(z,Sz_1,Sz_2,Sz_3)\gt 0 \}$..$(c)$

I understand that $(a)$=$(b)$ as the mobius transformation preserves cross ratio,but i don't quite understand how does $(b)$=$(c)$ ?

Also, if in particular $S$ is chosen so that it maps $\Gamma$ to $\Bbb R_\infty$ then $\{z:Im(z,z_1,z_2,z_3)\gt 0 \}$ is equal to $S^{-1}$ of either the upper or lower half plane. I don't follow this either, need some help out here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set in (c) consists of those $S^{-1} z$ with $\text{Im}(z, Sz_1, Sz_2, Sz_3) > 0$. Replacing the dummy variable $z$ with $Sz$ (with $S$ being a bijection) gives the result.

For the second part, use the fact that the cross ratio is invariant under Mobius transformations (and $\Gamma$ is arbitrary) to reduce the case of $S(z) = z$ and $(z_1, z_2, z_3) = (1, 0, \infty)$.